# For any subsets $S$ and $T$ of $Y, f^{-1}(S \cap T) = f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(T) ?$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets and $f:X \to Y$ be a function. Which one of the following statements is TRUE?

1. For any subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X, |f(A \cup B)| = |f(A)| + |f(B)|$
2. For any subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X, f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$
3. For any subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X, |f(A \cap B)| = \min \{|f(A)|, |f(B)|\}$
4. For any subsets $S$ and $T$ of $Y, f^{-1}(S \cap T) = f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(T)$

---

I consider a counter example , Let $x = \{ a , b , c \}$ and $y = \{ 1 , 2 \}$ ,and $f(a)=1 , f(b)=1 , f(c) =1$ . So options $(1) , (2)$ and $(3)$ is false , and $(4)$ is true .

Comment: @HenningMakholm To (2): $A= \{a\}$, $B=\{b\}$,  then $f(A \cap B) =\emptyset$, and $f(A) \cap f(B) = \{1\}$. And for (3) the same sets. Then $\mid f(A \cap B) \mid  = \mid \emptyset \mid \neq 1 = \min \{ \mid f(A) \mid , \mid f(B) \mid \}$.

Comment: @Hetebrij: Hmm, right.

Comment: But what is your question Silence?

Comment: I need explanation in formal way .

Comment: Well, you have proven that (1), (2) and (3) do not hold. So all you need to show that (4) always holds. And to do so, it is quite straight forward if you start from the definition of $f^{-1} (S \cap T)$.

Comment: option 4 is the only right one. the proof is a chasing matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worries for (4); just note that by definition we have
$$
f^{(-1)}(S \cap T) = \{ \xi \in X \mid f(\xi) \in S \cap T \} = \{ \xi \in X \mid f(\xi) \in S \} \cap \{ \xi \in X \mid f(\xi) \in T \}\\ = f^{(-1)}(S) \cap f^{(-1)}(T).
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x \in f^{-1} (S\cap T) \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in S\cap T \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in S \text{ and } f(x) \in T \Longleftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(S) \text{ and } x\in f^{-1}(T) \Longleftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}(S)\cap f^{-1}(T)$$